# Django render json response html

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, django-templates

I'm am trying to render a json response which returns a html page in the body after I send my parameters to the endpoint url but I haven't found any information of how to handle this in django. So far I was able to see the html in an empty template that I created using JsonResponse(response.text,safe=False) but it shows the html with the tags and all. I'm open to suggestions. Note: The json post is going to send all the parameters to the endpoint and in response I get an html page that I need to show the user for payment processing.

```
    headers = {'content-type': 'application/json'}
    url = 'https://paymentway.net/api.php'
    params ={
        "ClientId": "",
        "FirstName": fname,
        "LastName": lname,
        "Email": email,
        "Amount": amount,
        "InvoiceNumber": InvoiceNum 
    }
    

    response = requests.post(url, headers=headers, data= json.dumps(params))
```

Answer (score 1):

check [render_to_string()](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/templates/#django.template.loader.render_to_string)

```
from django.http import JsonResponse
from django.template.loader import render_to_string

...

  def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    ...
    return JsonResponse({
      'html': render_to_string('templates/form.html', context, request=request),
      ...
    })
```

Comment: the problem here is that context needs to be a dict while my json response is pure html code

Comment: @kennethLebron why would you send  a json response, if you need pure html?

Comment: I manage to do it using return HttpResponse(response.text)

Comment: I am sending a Json Post with some parameters and in return I get pure html code with those parameters passed.

Comment: @kennethLebron yep, then you should do HttpResponse, not JsonResponse,
although I learned to always think ahead a respond with json, cos one day you're gonna need to pass a status, messages, or whatever and you might run into problems ;)